# carbonate stout properly

Tags: carbonation

I don't think I explained myself right. I have a c02 canister and I have beer gas. Can I carbonate an Irish stout with the c02 take it off the c02 then took it up to the beer gas and get the same pour effect creamy head or do I have to carbonate the stout with just the beer gas for it to pour like a Guinness with the cascading effect? Sorry for the same question again as I am new and a bit dim at this.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is duplicate, but for the sake of clarity.

Yes you should do as you described.

The creamy head comes from the beer gas pushing the beer at far greater pressure than can be done with pure c02.

Do not carbonate with beer gas, it's ineffective. It's for serving stouts, or pushing beer in really long lines.

Comment: The reason it's called "carbonation" is because you use carbon dioxide!